# Undefined return in a 'then' chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I am building an app with node and angular and when I request this specific endpoint, I am getting returned with an empty array '[]'. I put the return statement in the final 'then' block, but this gets executed before the prior for loop.

How can I make this synchronous so that the realTemps array gets populated in the for loop, then it gets returned in the next then statement?

```
router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
var templates = [];
var realTemps = [];
const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
const decoded = jwt.verify(token[1], 'secretkey');
decodedFactoryId = decoded.factoryId

Template.findAllByFactoryId(decodedFactoryId)
    .then((results) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            // THIS IS AN AVOIDABLE LOOP, quadratic time must be prevented by correctly formatting the data (TODO)
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                if (results[i][j].id) {
                    templates.push(results[i][j].id)
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("templates: " + templates)
        for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
            console.log(templates[i])
            Template.findByTemplateId(templates[i]).then(result => {
                console.log("here is the result: " + JSON.stringify(result[0]))
                realTemps.push(result);
            })

        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        return realTemps;
    })
 })
```

Comment: `Template.findByTemplateId(templates[i]).then()` will still finish later than the outer `then()` chain. I suggest re-writing this with `await`s to make it simpler for yourself.

Comment: How could this be re-written into an await if it is in a request function?

Comment: By making it async or extracting that logic into an async function you then call, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply make the second and third .then as follows

```
.then(() => Promise.all(templates.map(template => Template.findByTemplateId(template))))
.then((realTemps) => {
    return realTemps;
})
```

Comment: The last `then()` here is superfluous.

Comment: yes, but that's where you'd **use** realTemps - the code in the question is far from compelte

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Promise.all` to wait for a list of promises.

```js
Template.findAllByFactoryId(decodedFactoryId)
    .then((results) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            // THIS IS AN AVOIDABLE LOOP, quadratic time must be prevented by correctly formatting the data (TODO)
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                if (results[i][j].id) {
                    templates.push(results[i][j].id)
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(() => {
      // Promise.all
      return Promise.all(templates.map(template => Template.findByTemplateId(template).then(result => {
        console.log("here is the result: " + JSON.stringify(result[0]))
        realTemps.push(result);
      })))
    })
    .then(() => {
        return realTemps;
    })
 })
```

For a better coding experience, I recommend you to use `async/await`, which is clearer than `.then` statements.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Promise.all()` inside second callback.

```
router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
var templates = [];
var realTemps = [];
const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
const decoded = jwt.verify(token[1], 'secretkey');
decodedFactoryId = decoded.factoryId

Template.findAllByFactoryId(decodedFactoryId)
    .then((results) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            // THIS IS AN AVOIDABLE LOOP, quadratic time must be prevented by correctly formatting the data (TODO)
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                if (results[i][j].id) {
                    templates.push(results[i][j].id)
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(() => Promise.all(templates.map(template => Template.findByTemplateId(template))))

    .then((tmpls) => {
        realTemps =  tmpls;
    })
 })
```

Or with **async/await** syntax:

```
router.get("", async (req, res, next) => {
  var templates = [];
  var realTemps = [];
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token[1], 'secretkey');
  decodedFactoryId = decoded.factoryId

  const results = await Template.findAllByFactoryId(decodedFactoryId);

  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    // THIS IS AN AVOIDABLE LOOP, quadratic time must be prevented by correctly formatting the data (TODO)
    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
      if (results[i][j].id) {
        templates.push(results[i][j].id)
      }
    }
  }

  realTemps = await Promise.all(templates.map(template => Template.findByTemplateId(template)));
})
```